# How to remove digits after decimal in a table in SQLite database

Tags: sqlite, floating-point, rounding

I have a database but in one column there are floating numbers. I want to remove the digits after the decimal point in a table in SQLite database. What query should be used to remove the digits after the decimal?

Comment: I would remove it in the resulting array instead of in the query.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

For round value: (2.34 = 2, 2.89 = 3)

```
SELECT round(column) FROM sample
```

For Floor value: (2.34 = 2, 2.89 = 2)

```
SELECT cast(column as int) FROM sample
```

Is this what you want ?